# Change DIV text with jQuery multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<h2 id="excTitle">
   <div id="titleText">
       <?=$exercises[$currentExc]?>
   </div>
</h2>
```

The above code displays a title.

```
<button type="button" class="styled-button-10b" onClick="skipExc()">Skip</button>
```

The above code calls the below function, which should change the title.

```
//Skip to the next exercise
function skipExc()
{
    <?php
         $currentExc++;
    ?>

    $("#titleText").html('<?php echo $exercises[$currentExc]; ?>');
}
```

It actually works, but only once.

Let's say I have 5 different titles (5 items in my $exercises array), the code above only go from the first title to the second title and then stops updating.

I have tested and the function is called, but the title doesn't change.

Can anybody please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: It works only once, as php is run before page load, so `<?php echo $exercises[$currentExc]; ?>` does not change once the page loads. You can either store `$exercises` as a javascript array, and increment through it, or you will need to use ajax to go back to the server/php to get the next value(s)

Comment: `$exercises[$currentExc];` was processed in server and returned a single value when it's arriving at the client end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode your php array to json and then update the counter/index via javascript

```js
var count = 0;
        
function skipExc() {
  var exercises = <?php echo json_encode($exercises); ?>;
            
  $("#titleText").html(exercises[count]);
        
  count++;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="excTitle">
  <div id="titleText"></div>
</h2>
<button type="button" class="styled-button-10b" onClick="skipExc()">Skip</button>
<?php $exercises = array('a', 'b', 'c'); ?>
```